# I'm having issues cast/converting the dw datepart of GetDate()[3] so I can find it in a string [1,3,5]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the datepart is returned as an int. The string lives in WeeklyFreq column with nvarchar data type in the Alerts table.

I've tried every variation of cast and convert, but to no avail. The Google has let me down as well.

I'm missing something that must be very obvious here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM Alerts
WHERE DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) IN 
(SELECT WeeklyFreq
FROM Alerts
WHERE Id = 1)
```

Thank you both very much for your input. The solution seems to be:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         Alerts
WHERE     ((SELECT     WeeklyFreq
FROM         Alerts
WHERE     Id = 1) LIKE 
N'%' + CAST(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) AS  nvarchar(2)) + N'%')
```

I agree that storing the data in separate columns rather than in a string would be the proper solution, but circumstances don't allow for that at this juncture.

How do I accept both of your answers as the best choice?

The big picture looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_QueueOrdersWeeklyBetween] AS
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @VendorId int
DECLARE @SurveyId int
DECLARE @DealerId int
DECLARE @ItemId int
DECLARE @Email nvarchar(255)
DECLARE Transaction_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT     Orders.Id, Orders.VendorId, Orders.SurveyId, Orders.DealerId,  Orders.ItemId, Retailers.Email
FROM         Orders INNER JOIN
                  Retailers ON Retailers.DealerId = Orders.DealerId INNER JOIN
                  Alerts ON Alerts.VendorId = Orders.VendorId
WHERE     (Orders.Queued = 0) AND (Orders.SurveyQueued = 0) AND (Alerts.Occurs = 3) AND (DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 
                  Alerts.WeeklyDailyFreqEveryStart AND Alerts.WeeklyDailyFreqEveryEnd - 1) AND (Alerts.Alert1 = 1) AND (Alerts.WeeklyDailyFreq = 2) AND 
                  (Alerts.WeeklyFreq LIKE N'%' + CAST(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) AS nvarchar(2)) + N'%')
OPEN Transaction_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Transaction_Cursor
INTO @Id, @VendorId, @SurveyId, @DealerId, @ItemId, @Email
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MailQueue (OrderId, VendorId, SurveyId, DealerId, ItemId, MailedTo, WhenQueued) 
VALUES (@Id, @VendorId, @SurveyId, @DealerId, @ItemId, @Email, GetDate())
UPDATE Orders SET Queued = 1 WHERE ID = @Id
FETCH NEXT FROM Transaction_Cursor
INTO @Id, @VendorId, @SurveyId, @DealerId, @ItemId, @Email
END
CLOSE Transaction_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Transaction_Cursor
GO
```

Comment: Some example data and expected outcome is usually useful. Also, you should probably tag this with sql-server if it's specific to Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @Tom Added sql-server. This is part of a much more complicated query that queues email alerts based on criteria supplied by users such as, alert me if I have orders pending every hour from 9 am to 5 pm on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday. I'm looking to test the day of the week against their preference Mon, Wed, Fri. [1,3,5]

Comment: This last edit of yours selects ALL ROWS of the Alerts table if the Row having ID=1 matches your criteria. I can't imagine any scenario where that would make sense. And to answer your last sencence, you can't accept two answers.

Comment: @takrl - The issue was a smaller part of the big picture. I've posted the entire SP above. Thanks again for all of your help. I truly appreciate it. Like to buy you both a drink. I'm clicking on your check-mark as the answer, but I do appreciate both of your inputs. Cheers!

Comment: As a final remark, performance of this depends on table size and, of course, field indices. If you're going to use this I'd definetly put an index on WeeklyFreq. Looking at the execution plan of the select statement on its own will give you hints how to index for best performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how the `IN` operator works, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177682%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). You say that weeklyfreq is of type nvarchar, so this seems to contain a comma-separated list of the values you want to check against. Otherwise I couldn't see a reason why you'd limit the subquery to a single row. For the IN operator to work the column would have to be of type int as well.

What could work in this case:

```
SELECT * FROM Alerts
  WHERE N'%' + cast(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) as nvarchar(2)) + N'%' LIKE 
  (SELECT weeklyfreq FROM Alerts WHERE Id = 1)
```

This assumes that weeklyfreq contains a series of one-digit numbers. Also, this will only work as long as the subquery returns only a single row. The current day of week is converted to varchar and enclosed in '%' to make the `LIKE` operator work.

But I would not recommend to use this; if you can, store your data in a different way that allows for easier analysis.

Also, I can't quite see where exactly you're going with this. For this to make any sense, the Alerts table of the outer select should be either referenced in the WHERE clause or within the subquery (that would then be a [correlated subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx)).

The only thing I can see that'd make sense is to lose the subquery, then it'd be

```
SELECT * FROM Alerts
  WHERE weeklyfreq LIKE N'%' + cast(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) as nvarchar(2)) + N'%'
```

This you can additionally filter for an user's ID by adding to the WHERE clause.

Comment: The issue was a smaller part of the big picture. I've posted the entire SP above. Thanks again for all of your help. I truly appreciate it. Like to buy you both a drink. I'm clicking on your check-mark as the answer, but I do appreciate both of your inputs. Cheers! [I think I posted this in the wrong place]

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote either of your answers as this is the first time I've used Stack Overflow. I only have a rep of 3.

Comment: Don't worry, that'll change as time passes. I believe it already has since I see an 8 on your profile.

Answer (score 2):

As takrl points out, if you're storing this information in a single column as a comma-delimited list of values, that's a big mistake. One of the most important rules of database design is that a column should only hold one piece of data.

There are several ways to handle this. Probably the easiest would be to have separate columns for each day of the week. Another possibility would be to use a bit map. This also stores more than one piece of information in the column, but bitmaps are much easier to work with than strings for something like this.

You could also have a separate table for Alert_Days which could contain a row for each day of the week that an Alert is active.

Performing this query with any of these designs would be trivial.

When you have a string column such as '1, 3, 5' that is treated by SQL Server as a single, distinct value. It doesn't make sense to ask if 2 is in '1, 3, 5' because to SQL Server '1, 3, 5' is not a list of numbers - it's a single string.

Lastly, the use of Alerts in your subquery doesn't make a lot of sense to me, so I have a feeling that you're doing something wrong there as well. Or maybe it's just me.

Comment: I don't think it's just you. At least, it's me too ;-)

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote either of your answers as this is the first time I've used Stack Overflow. I only have a rep of 3.